# Getting captcha screen when I execute automation scripts using chrome browser

Tags: selenium, google-chrome

I have been executing automation scripts for last 6 months without any issues. Suddenly chrome browser shows captcha screen and shows message that please confirm are you human ?.

Below that it states 2 points 1.JavaScript might be disabled 2. your cookies are  not supported .I enabled both of the Java script and cookies but no luck.

I tried to execute older version of chrome browser also but I am getting same captcha screen in the older version of browser too.

The good thing is that I am not getting captcha screen in Firefox and edge browser. I am getting it only in  the chrome browser.

May I know if chrome has introduced any functionality like if we execute automation scripts and it shows captcha screen because why I am getting this doubt that firefox and edge is not showing captcha screen.

Comment: Which site in chrome? It is Google's reCaptcha v2 or v3 with invisible option?

Comment: It is recaptcha v2. Sorry it is my client url so I could not give it